# Lambda pack capture with ellipsis on both sides - what is the meaning?

Tags: c++, lambda, variadic-templates, c++20

[P0780 *("Allow pack expansion in lambda init-capture")*](http://wg21.link/p0780), approved for C++20, allows to generate a pack of closure data members by placing an ellipsis (`...`) before a pack expansion as part of a lambda capture.

This is useful - for example - when capturing a pack by move:

```
template <typename... Ts>
void foo(Ts... xs)
{
    bar([...xs = std::move(xs)]{ /* ... */ });
}
```

While playing around with this feature, I came up with this cryptic construction:

```
template <typename... Ts>
void foo(Ts... xs)
{
    [...xs...]{}();
}

int main()
{
    foo(0, 1, 2);
}
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/r8La1S)

g++ (trunk) compiles it, but I am honestly struggling to understand its meaning. What is this supposed to mean? What will the generate closure have as data members?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It should be ill-formed. Filed [89686](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=89686) (... and already fixed!) The grammar in [[expr.prim.lambda.capture]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#nt:capture) is:

> *capture*:
>       *simple-capture* `...`<sub>opt</sub>
>       `...`<sub>opt</sub> *init-capture*

You can **either** have a *simple-capture* (which would be `xs...`) **or** you can have an *init-capture* (which would be `...xs=xs`, an *init-capture* needs to have an *initializer*). You cannot have both in one go.